# Symfony2: loading user roles from database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm running into a problem with the Symfony2 Security system, particularly when trying to load Roles from a database.  Before going further, I am aware of FOSUserBundle, but at the moment, in an effort to better understand the Symfony2 framework, I want to try and make my bundle work using Symfony2 components only. TL;DR -> please don't tell me to just use the FOSUserBundle.  :-)

I have 3 entities configured in my bundle, Accounts, AccountsRoles, and AccountsRepository.

**src\RedK\Core\IndexBundle\Entity\Accounts.php**
http://pastebin.com/0VgXvtJp

**src\RedK\Core\IndexBundle\Entity\AccountsRoles.php**
http://pastebin.com/GiKNnYg3

**src\RedK\Core\IndexBundle\Entity\AccountsRepository.php**
http://pastebin.com/SVuMVdpN

**MySQL demo_template.accounts Table**
http://pastebin.com/YzmjD9e4

**MySQL demo_template.accounts_roles Table**
http://pastebin.com/Ybwr4f7y

All aspects of the bundle were working correctly (registration, confirmation, password reset, and login) before I attempted to add the loading of user roles from a database. When I simply set the role to array('ROLE_USER') via the getRoles() { return array('ROLE_USER') }, authentication worked and the user successfully logged into the site.

However, upon attempting to integrate roles from the database, I receive the following error, which I understand is an instance of AuthenticationException:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/humplebert/Websites/www/template/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php line 804
```

**Stack Trace**
http://pastebin.com/Sr5RvZaY

The exception is only generated when I modify the query in AccountsRepository and remove
the "->select()" and "->leftJoin()" components. In looking at the Stack Trace, around line 16 on the pastebin.com link, it appears I have all sorts of "crazy" happening with regards to the many-to-many mapping in the BasicEntityPersister.

I've searched high and low in my Entity classes for any reference to plain "id" and can find none.  I've noticed that if I change the names of my "ID" columns in my entities to just "id" (i.e. replace "AccountsID" with "id" in src\RedK\Core\IndexBundle\Entity\Accounts) the error goes away (and is replaced with another error, more on that in a moment).

**Question 1)**
Is there something blatently wrong with my Entities to be generating the "Undefined index: id" error I am receiving?  If not, does Symfony2/Doctrine2 require that Auto-Increment columns in be labeled "id"?

As I have continued to tinker, I decided to try renaming my table ID columns to "id". Therefore, src\RedK\Core\IndexBundle\Accounts replaces AccountsID with just "id". And likewise, src\RedK\Core\IndexBundle\AccountsRoles replaces RolesID with just "id". Upon doing so, the "Undefined index: id" error goes away. However, I am presented with a new error: `"table or view demo_template.accounts_accountsroles does not exist"`.  Well of course it doesn't exist, I don't have a table defined as accounts_accountsroles. I have two tables, accounts and accounts_roles.

**Question 2)**
In order to use the Symfony2/Doctrine2 tools for importing user roles from a database, what rules are there regarding the naming of the tables?  Based on the error I received, it seems that some form of concatenation is taking place. Or have I just simply screwed up my annotations somewhere along the line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still stuck on this error.  I am attaching the MySQL structures for the two database tables in the hopes it will help shed additional light on the problem.

Comment: You should put the stack trace instead of only the error (ie, message, file and line ...).

Comment: In most databases (including MySQL) many to many relationship require a third 'junction' table. If you don't specify the name of this table in your annotations Symfony generates it by concatenating the names of the two entities - thus the accounts_accountsroles table which does need to exist in order for your many to many relationship to work. It may be simply that your database schema is out of date or there may be an issue with your many to many annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Question 1) the short answer is no! For the long answer see section 5.3 Mapping Defaults in the Doctrine [Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) documentation:

It states that if you use this short annotation:

```
/** @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group") */
private $groups;
```

"In that case, the name of the join table defaults to a combination of the simple, unqualified class names of the participating classes, separated by an underscore character. The names of the join columns default to the simple, unqualified class name of the targeted class followed by “_id”. The referencedColumnName always defaults to “id”, just as in one-to-one or many-to-one mappings."

You can override the defaults by providing more detailed many to many annotations (see link above) and therefore avoid the id error.

Regarding Question 2) the concatenation is correct. Many to many relationships require a third 'junction' table. The Doctrine paragraph above explains how the name of this table is generated.

I don't know why the 'table ... does not exist' error is occurring for the junction table as the annotations look ok to me. It appears as though your database schema is somehow out of sync with your annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution, above FOSUserBundle and described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718628/fosuserbundle-override-roles-property-roles-in-acme-demobundle-entity-user/24612877#24612877)

After implementing Role access throug Doctrine you still need to make a RoleHierarchy service aware of it.